# Loop through worksheets and apply ONLY (!) a set of conditional formatting on all other worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

How can I only transfer the conditional formatting of one sheet to all other sheets? Any tricks with xlPaste and xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats etc. don't work, since my code is copying ranges via a dictionary.

```
 Sub LoopSheets()

        
 Dim ws As Worksheet

         For Each ws In Worksheets

            ' Loop through all sheets after sheet 1, and Copy ONLY the conditional formatting rules from sheet 1 to the others.
            
            

         Next

      End Sub
```

Code is not written by me but I got a lot of help from someone on this site. I tried my best to understand it. I marked some of my ideas.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractCompanyData_NoComp()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "MasterTable"
    Const DATA_COLUMNS As String = "A:K"
    Const DATE_COLUMN As Long = 6
'   Const COMPANY_COLUMN As Long = 8
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_DATE_FORMAT As String = "dd\/mm\/yyyy"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME_DATE_FORMAT As String = "ddd dd.mm.yyyy"
    Const COPY_HEADERS As Boolean = True
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Return the source data in an array ('sData').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange.Columns(DATA_COLUMNS)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' An Incomplete Description of the Dictionary and the Collection
    ' A dictionary consists of two arrays: one is called 'Keys' and the other
    ' is called 'Items' ('Values'). Each key has an associated item
    ' and they form a so-called 'key-value pair'.
    ' Each key needs to be unique while its item can hold various data types,
    ' in this case, a collection ('object').
    ' A collection is similar but simpler.
    ' Each of a collection's 'item' needs to be unique.
    ' The collection is used because it is more efficient and you can simply
    ' add just an item to it while you need to add a value pair to a dictionary.
    
    ' Return the unique dates ('sDate') from the source array ('sData')
    ' in the 'keys' of a dictionary.
    ' Each key's corresponding 'item' will hold a collection whose 'items'
    ' will hold the rows ('sr') where each date ('sDate', key) was found.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim sDate As Variant, sr As Long
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount ' skip headers
        sDate = sData(sr, DATE_COLUMN)
        If IsDate(sDate) Then
            If Not dict.Exists(sDate) Then
                ' Create the 'sDate' key in the dictionary
                ' and add a new collection to the key's associated item.
                dict.Add sDate, New Collection
                ' or:
                'Set dict(sDate) = New Collection
            End If
            dict(sDate).Add sr ' add the row to the items of the collection
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Loop through the keys (dates) of the dictionary, and by applying
    ' the required logic, copy the data to the destination worksheet.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim dws As Worksheet, drg As Range, ddrg As Range
    Dim dData() As Variant, sRow As Variant
    Dim dr As Long, idr As Long, drCount As Long, c As Long
    Dim dwsName As String
'   Dim Company As String, IsCompanyFound As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the keys (dates) of the dictionary.
    For Each sDate In dict.Keys
        
        ' Define the destination array.
        drCount = dict(sDate).Count - COPY_HEADERS
        ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
        
        ' Write the headers to the destination array.
        ' Also, determine the used destination array rows ('idr', 'dr')
        ' i.e. the inital row, the first row to be written to minus one.
        If COPY_HEADERS Then
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(1, c) = sData(1, c)
            Next c
            idr = 1
        Else
            idr = 0
        End If
        dr = idr
        
        ' Loop through the items ('sRow') of the collection ('dict(sDate)'),
        ' held by the current key's ('dDate') corresponding item ('dict(sDate)'),
        ' and write the values from each corresponding row ('sRow')
        ' of the source array ('sData') to the next row ('dr')
        ' of destination array ('dData') skipping the company column.
        ' Also, attempt to determine the company name.
        For Each sRow In dict(sDate)
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                    dData(dr, c) = sData(sRow, c)
            Next c
        Next sRow

        
        ' Determine the destination worksheet name ('dwsName').
        dwsName = Format(sDate, DST_SHEET_NAME_DATE_FORMAT)
        
        ' Delete an existing same named sheet.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            On Error Resume Next
                wb.Sheets(dwsName).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        ' Add a new worksheet ('dws') and rename it accordingly.
        'insert right after all sheets
        Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        
        
        ' Copy the values from the destination array ('dData')
        ' to the destination range ('drg').
        Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(drCount, cCount)
        drg.Value = dData
        
        ' Apply formatting to the destination (range, worksheet).
        With drg
            ' Format headers and reference the destination data range ('ddrg').
            If COPY_HEADERS Then
                With .Rows(1)
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
                Set ddrg = drg.Resize(drCount - 1).Offset(1)
            Else
                Set ddrg = drg
            End If
            ' Format the destination data range ('ddrg').
            With ddrg
                ' Format the destination date column.
                With ddrg.Columns(DATE_COLUMN)
                    .NumberFormat = DST_DATE_FORMAT
                End With
            End With
            ' Format the entire destination columns.
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit

       
'XYZ        'Copy Name to Header, delete second row
            .dws.Range("E1") = .dws.Range("E2")
            .Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
'XYZ

    End With
        
    Next sDate
    
    'Additional Ideas
    
    'sws.Activate
    wb.Save

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Daten wurden extrahiert", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Section marked with "XYZ":
This didn't work. Can I use .Cells("E1").Value?
How can I deduce myself, whether range can use .cells or .value, do I really have to try it out myself everytime?

Comment: Do you understand the code you pasted? Do you want applying conditional formatting to only containing `Date` cells? Then, can you better explain (**in words**) what you try doing... Do all the sheets in discussion have an identic used range? Are all the cells conditionally formatted in the same way (using the same way/rules)? If it is difficult to explain as it should what I am asking above, at least, picture(s) to show what you have and what you need maybe will help us understanding what you try accomplishing...

Comment: Let me try again, I have a bad day. I basically only have one question: How to apply the conditional formatting rules of one sheet to all other sheets? 
I know I can do stuff like this:
`MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=100", Formula2:="=150" `
But how do I know what the formatting formula I installed looks like in VBA?

The rest is basically: Here is a bunch of code I don't understand. If you wish, insert it for me but I rather want to show I tried. It was an attempt to say "I'm here, I want to get there, guide me a bit".

Comment: Your XYZ has drg (range) .dws (worksheet) . Range("E1") (another range), this will fail ---- Try `With dws.Range("E2") : .Offset(-1).Value = .Value : .EntireRow.Delete : End With`. As for your other issue, I believe you're trying to have a cake and eat it too. The code (from vBasic2000) creates an array to paste values in one go without using `.Copy` but that's the exact reason that makes copying conditional formatting more difficult. As far as I can tell, it'd be easier to reapply the conditional formatting with your new ranges or not use the method vBasic showed.

Comment: What you want is stated in your question title. What you really want accomplishing is related to my comment. Is it so difficult to try answering my clarification questions? A solution, a fast one is related to your answers. If you only kike asking, I am afraid that only guessing what you have against what you need I cannot help you. If you need conditional formatting **only part of the sheet cells** using the same format rules is one approach, similar used ranges with **the same condition formatting** is something else. Your code  is not of any help, I am afraid. Your explanations may be...

Comment: @Notus_Panda And that's what I figured out, too. Now I try to loop through all newly generated sheets (starting loop after mastertable), then apply the conditional formatting with my attempt, where you basically manually place the rules on the sheet. I tried with macro recorder but then I asked for some kind of documentation how to effectively deduce how to creat these rules manually.

Comment: @FaneDuru  I know, that impelementing usual conditional formatting tricks doesn't work as easy here, I placed the code to avoid questions a la "show us the code", which doesn't help here at all with this issue, it seems. It is not easy for new and neurodivergent people to ask questions properly, I appreciate all help I can get.

Comment: If you do not learn about answering our clarification questions, even after I pointed it out again, it is difficult to be helped, I am afraid... You are always focusing on secondary aspects and missing the point...

Comment: Maybe I simply don't get the point? Maybe someone else can reword you, so you're better comprehensible? The guy below you did get my question.

Answer (score 1):

- The quickest way to apply conditional formatting to another sheet is to copy and paste the format.
- If there are formats on target sheets that cannot be overwritten by `Sheet1`, you will have to copy conditional formatting rules one by one.
- There are more than 10 types of conditional formatting, and they may have different properties. The provided code is a sample for `xlExpression`.
- If more formats (beside Interior.Color and Font.Color) are used on `Sheet1`, modification is needed.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFC()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, Sht As Worksheet
    Dim targetRng As Range
    Dim oFC As FormatCondition, newFC As FormatCondition
    Set srcSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each Sht In Sheets
        If Not Sht.Name = srcSht.Name Then
            For Each oFC In srcSht.Cells.FormatConditions
                Select Case oFC.Type
                Case Is = xlExpression
                    Set newFC = Sht.Range(oFC.AppliesTo.Address).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=oFC.Formula1)
                    newFC.Interior.Color = oFC.Interior.Color
                    newFC.Font.Color = oFC.Font.Color
                    newFC.StopIfTrue = oFC.StopIfTrue
                Case Is = xlTextString
                    ' ..
                ' Case Is = <All XlFormatConditionType types which are implemented on sheet1>
                End Select
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [XlPasteType enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

| Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xlAboveAverageCondition | 12 | Above average condition |
| xlBlanksCondition | 10 | Blanks condition |
| xlCellValue | 1 | Cell value |
| xlColorScale | 3 | Color scale |
| xlDataBar | 4 | DataBar |
| xlErrorsCondition | 16 | Errors condition |
| xlExpression | 2 | Expression |
| xlIconSet | 6 | Icon set |
| xlNoBlanksCondition | 13 | No blanks condition |
| xlNoErrorsCondition | 17 | No errors condition |
| xlTextString | 9 | Text string |
| xlTimePeriod | 11 | Time period |
| xlTop10 | 5 | Top 10 values |
| xlUniqueValues | 8 | Unique values |

Comment: Won't the formulas used be warped due to the ranges being different from the main sheet? That's why I didn't think looping through the CF rules was a viable solution here.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I agree. To be honest, I don't know. The provided code is just a demostration. Fine tunning may be needed.

Comment: @Notus_Panda  The rules I'm using are simple ones as "If there is a unique codeword in the cell, as "_construction_site_owner" and "_construction_site_name", then colour the cell. This creates a nice visual orientation. My issue is now: How can I find out how my conditional formatting rules look like in vba, i.e. the exact arguments?

Comment: In the second for loop (FormatConditions), you can check the formula with what taller used to set it to the new sheet: `Debug.Print oFC.Formula1` that should be what you're looking for, right? Like previously mentioned however, `oFC.AppliesTo.Address` might be different.